# How can one save a macro and use it?

Tags: blend-files

In most of the software I have used like Coreldraw and Microsoft Word the user can save a series of keystrokes by making a Macro, called an Action in Adobe products. How can the user make a macro in Blender? The video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMxkU350SaE seems to show this, but is unclear since it doesn't seem to me that the author showed how to save and how the use the macro. Is there any other video tutorial describing how I can make a macro?

Comment: I agree that the video is not up to what I consider the author's usual standards of clarity, but at the end of the cited video tutorial, the author invites users to contact him with questions. This might be the most useful course of action, to contact Alex.

Comment: yes but here there are many expert who listen and reply quickly and understand what we need and solve the solution in time.

Comment: This is best explained with an example. Maybe add what kind of actions you want to use in your macro. Otherwise it will have the same effect as that tutorial, which is quite clear to me.

Comment: I don't think Blender as any macro capabilities in the sense that other software does, it does have a pretty complete scripting interface through it's Python API, which allows to make very complex commands and workflows

Comment: @Atek, I suspect many of those same experts you seek to query also monitor one or more of the forums on the coding section of the [Blender Artists fiorums](https://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?47-Coding). I think you'll get responses just as quickly, and from experts just as knowledgeable (and perhaps some of the experts on Stackexchange also monitor those forums). I wonder if some of your confusion stems from insufficient familiarity with Python, and suggest you make sure you coding skills are in proper form.